# C# LINQ How to get a data source from a db?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am trying use LINQ in a C# program to get information from a database. I have found a lot of examples showing basic to advanced queries, but I can't find anything to get a basic database connection. See basic LINQ example below:

```
var adultNames = from person in people
                 where person.Age >= 18
                 select person.Name;
```

I just can't figure out how to get to a specific database table and return information out of it. I want to be able to connect to a db table and return some information out of it. Thanks!

Comment: I assume the examples you are looking at don't show that you have to first create a dataset first. Once you create the dataset you can then refer to it in code like above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres a very simple way to connect to a database although I suggest you read the app config afterwards and other parts of your project to see how it works.

In the menu strip go to Data -> Add New Data Source. From here pick database then entity data model. Follow the rest of the steps to create a datasource for your project.

In your program you can create an object of the datasource by using:

WhatYouCalledTheDataSource datasourceObject = new WhatYouCalledTheDataSource();

You can then make queries on this object by changing your first line of the query to:

```
var adultNames = from person in datasourceObject.people
```

to get the data you want, once you have the query you can place the results into a list like:

```
List<string> queryResults = new List<string>();

queryResults.AddRange(adultNames);
```

bearing in mind that I basing on the thought that name would be a string.
You can also create lists based on tables like

```
var adultNames = from person ...
                 ...
                 select person;
List<people> queryResults = new List<people>();
queryResults.AddRange(adultNames);
```

Comment: I didn't realize how easy it was to add a data source. That is what I had been missing. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have been looking at examples of LINQ, which allows you to query from a data set. What you need in addition is called an Object Relational Mapper (ORM). Look at [LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) or [The Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials) (newer) to get starts with this. This layer will introspect a database and create a lot of infrastructure to pull data out for you based on the data model.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Linq to Sql, then this may help: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx
entity framework: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c15489

Comment: I found this blog earlier and it did have some useful information. I just didn't see how he was accessing the data source, and that is what I was struggling with.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to retrieve data from a database.  ADO.NET is the general technology.  Your specific options are:

**System.Data/SqlClient/ODP**

You can use the standard query system in ADO.NET to get data from any database that uses ODBC, or use native data providers such as SqlClient or ODP.  The `SqlClient` namespace may be used to get data from SQL Server.  The Oracle Data Provider (ODP) is used with Oracle.

You have to write the queries/stored procedures yourself using "raw" ADO.NET.

Here is an excellent listing of ADO.NET example code:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx

Here is a link to Oracle's ODP:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

**LINQ to SQL**

LINQ to SQL is a LINQ provider specifically for the SQL Server database.  It is still supported, but is superseded by Entity Framework.

More detail here:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

**Entity Framework**

Entity Framework works natively with SQL Server and can work with Oracle using third-party or open-source data providers.

Entity Framework 4/4.1 will allow you to use an *Entity Data Model* (EDM) as an abstraction of your database.  The EDM will surface a set of objects with which you can interact, and a Context object is used to retrieve/commit data to the database.  The CRUD queries are dynamically generated from your LINQ syntax, so you don't have to write T-SQL or PL-SQL queries yourself in most cases.

Here is a basic example of Entity Framework:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sample_entity_framework.aspx

Answer (score 2):

if you have a database table people then you can use LINQ-to-SQL to return information from it, first you need to reference the following two assemblies.

```
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
```

define the following entity like this:

```
[table]
class people
{
    [column]
    public int Age { get; set; };
    [column] 
    public string Name { get; set; };
}
```

then you can write tour query against database

```
Datacontext db = new DataContext("database Connection String");
var adultNames = from person in db.GetTable<people>()
             where person.Age >= 18
             select person.Name;
```

Comment: I saw an example where it added the to assemblies, and at the time they wouldn't work. I didn't even think of having add the reference to the project. Your answer made me thank of that. Thanks!

Do you have any examples of how a "database Connection String" should be formated?

Comment: this is an example: `"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NewAcademy;Integrated Security=True"`, you can get this string from the server explorer in VS and then choose the database, in the properties window you will find the connectiostring property, for more information about how it is formatted see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at this NerdDinner [pdf file](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf) that creates a MVC solution, it shows step by step how to create a dataset using Linq to SQL